# Are types allowed to be specified for return-type-requirement in a requires expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, requires-expression

Look at this simple concept example:

```
template <typename T>
requires requires(T t) { { t+t } -> bool; }
void fn() {
}

int main() {
    fn<bool>();
}
```

Here, I used `bool` as the `type-constraint` of `return-type-requirement`. The current draft [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#1):

> type-constraint:
>
> nested-name-specifier opt concept-name
>
> nested-name-specifier opt concept-name < template-argument-list opt  >

So `type-constraint` must be a `concept-name`. Is `bool` (or any type) allowed as a concept name? If yes, what does it mean, and where does the draft standard allow it? I'd think that as `bool` is not a concept, so this is not allowed. Yet, both gcc and clang compile my example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/g9-R3J)

(Of course, it makes sense to allow types, I just don't see where the standard allows this, and what it means exactly: should types match exactly? Or conversions can happen?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is `bool` (or any type) allowed as a concept name?

No, `bool` (or any type) are not concepts. They are types.

The original design, and the Concepts TS, did allow types. That is, you could write a compound requirement like:

```
{ E } -> int;
```

But this was removed from C++20 by [P1452R2](https://wg21.link/p1452). There were a number of reasons this was removed, one of the motivations being what it would interfere with a future direction of wanting to adopt a generalized form of `auto`, like `vector<auto>` or `vector<Concept>`.

What the type requirement allowed you to express, you already can anyway, by whichever of:

```
{ E } -> std::same_as<int>;
{ E } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
```

was intended. Which also answers your question of what the type requirement actually meant - matching exactly or allowing conversions.

Comment: When I looked up `same_as` it takes in two types, similar to `is_same`, except it's a concept. How does this work? Is `E` substituted as the first or the second parameter, or something else entirely?

Comment: @user975989 first template parameter.